# Python: two "yield"s in one function

Tags: python, yield, coroutine

We find an interesting issue on `yield` of Python. We wrote a simple program:

```
def F():
    for i in range(5, 9):
        for j in range(21, 29):
            x = yield i
            y = (yield j) * 100
            x += y
            print '>>>', x

gen = F()
next(gen)
a1 = gen.send(66)
a2 = gen.send(77)
print a1
print a2
```

The result is amazing:

```
>>> 7766
21
5
```

i=5, j=21 => yield i => a1=21 => send(66) => x = 66

i=5, j=21 => yield j => a2=5 => send(77) => y = 7700

print 7766

print 21

print 5

i.e. after `yield i`, `a1` gets the value of `j`; after `yield j`, `a2` gets the value of `i`.

Does anyone know why `yield` do like this? Why not a1=5, a2=21?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`next(gen)` takes the first element from the generator (`i`):

```
next(gen) # 5
```

Then `gen.send(66)` is equal to `j` (which is 21). Since your second loop is still working, subsequent `gen.send(77)` is equal to `i` (which is still 5).

Essentially, the problem is that you consume *3* values, instead of *2*.

Use [`gen.send(None)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator.send) or `next(gen)` to start the generator:

```
a1 = gen.send(None) # or a1 = next(gen)
a2 = gen.send(77)
print(a1, a2) # prints 5 21
```

Answer (score 1):

`next(gen)` calls into the method, which returns from the first `yield i`. Your `a1 = gen.send(66)` then resumes the method at `y = (yield j) * 100` and yields `j` from there. The `a2 = gen.send(77)` line resumes the method directly afterwards and returns from `x = yield i`.